# OR STATEMENT TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

I'm trying to get a RockPaperScissors program working.

I'm getting this error and I feel like I've tried everything, I think I'm just not getting the "or" statement formatted properly.

This is the code I have:

```
def userPick():
    userChoice = input("Enter a (1) for rock, (2) for paper, (3) for scissors, or (0) to quit:\n")
    userChoice == int(input, userChoice < 0 or userChoice > 3.0)
    print("Invalid choice. Try again.\n")
    userChoice = int(userChoice)
    return userChoice
```

Comment: userChoice is a string. you can't compare it to an int (number) without converting it first

Comment: You use non-existing syntax.  You probably want to have `if` statement.

Comment: You probably need a loop as well, if you do not want to return a value that has not passed your validation.

Comment: @PM77-1, it _exists_, though it doesn't make much sense. `string == int(function, boolean)` is going to throw an exception, sure, but that exception isn't a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first convert `userChoice` to an `int` after the input is taken in order to be able to compare it to another `int`. In your code `userChoice` is still a string.

Since you have to ask the user to input the choice again if he chose an invalid answer, you need to use an infinite while loop here which only breaks if the choice is valid.

```
def userPick():
    while(True):
        userChoice = int(input("Enter a (1) for rock, (2) for paper, (3) for scissors, or (0) to quit:\n"))
        if(userChoice<0 or userChoice>3):
            print("Invalid choice. Try again.\n")
        else:
            break
    return userChoice
```

Comment: `if` is not a function so you can drop the parentheses (for `while` it's the same). `if(userChoice<0 or userChoice>3):`  should be `if userChoice < 0 or userChoice > 3:`. Or maybe even better: `if not 0 <= user_choice <=3:`

Comment: I guess it's personal preference, it's something I've carried on from my C and Java coding days. Both work just fine. For the if statement, OP already had that code and based on the question is still a beginner to Python, so I didn't want to confuse him with too many changes. Anyways thanks for the suggestion :)